# Binding SFDX Commands to VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

There are SFDX commands that I would like to bind to a key combo in VS Command but I'm unsure how I would do this. For example, rather then using the `CMD`+`SHFT`+`P` to run `SFDX: Execute Anonymous Apex with Editor Contents` I would rather bind it to a chord like `CMD`+`ALT`+`E`,`A`. I can see from the console that running that outputs this command:

`sfdx force:apex:execute --apexcodefile /~/.sfdx/tools/tempApex.input`

Is there a way to bind this to a key command/chord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just looked this up in the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings), it's pretty easy.

First, open the Command Palette and choose `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts`, or use the menu File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.

In the search bar, type `sfdx execute`, and from there, choose the one you'd like to use, click the "+" icon to add a new key binding, and type in the command (e.g. Cmd+Alt+E A), and press Enter. The effect takes place immediately.

You can also add a When filter to make sure you don't "accidentally" fire off this command when you're in an invalid context (e.g. `editorTextFocus`).